# Copy file from pod to GCE bucket

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, go-cd

I am using gocd for ci/cd. Result is tar archive. I need to copy resulting tar to GCE bucket.

I have gocd-agent docker image with included google sdk.

I know how to use gcloud with service account from local machine, but not from inside pod.

How to use service account assigned to pod with gcloud auth on pod?

Final goal is to use gsutil to copy above mentioned archive to bucket in same project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought would be to create `Secret` based on the service account, reference it in a pod yaml definiton to mount to some file and then run `gcloud auth` from the pod using that file. There's more info in Google cloud [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform#step_4_import_credentials_as_a_secret).
Another option which is quite new is to use [Workload Identitiy](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity). Seems you'd need to configure GKE cluster to enable this option. And it's working for some versions of GKE.

Comment: Thanks, that part I know. Problem is gocd-agent which is destroyed after all jobs are done for that agent. What you said is more for pod that is going to stay alive. Edit: I will check this doc in details, maybe it does not matter if pod is destroyed.

Comment: About workload identity, I will check on it, but I think it is not possible for now.

Comment: What if to makeboth deployment (which would create pod) and secret part of helm chart, so they both are created when go-cd job is running?

Comment: There is already secret, which is cool. It is barely documented installation so it took me some time to figure it out. It has kubernetes secret with service account. I've created new bucket and added service account with write permissions. Tests and update will follow.

Comment: Your guidance was correct. With secret already included, only thing that was needed was to create new gocd-agent docker image that will include `gcloud` installed. Since secret was already included in pod definition, only thing that was needed is to point to `credentials.json` before each `gsutil` run.